# Capturing packets sent from a Restful service

Tags: rest, jersey, wildfly, packet-capture

I want to capture and encrypt the data in each packet sent from a Restful service with Wildfly app server as infrastructure.
Is there a method to capture theses packets using Jersey library?

Comment: What does the Jersey documentation say?

Comment: @RossJacobs Jersey documentation did not refer to this!